# group by and return zero if no value is present in Django

Tags: django

```
def get_queryset(self):
    date = datetime.date.today()
    current_year = date.today().year
    queryset = Subscription.objects.filter(created__year=current_year)\
        .exclude(user__is_staff=True).values(
            month=TruncMonth('created')
        ).annotate(
            total_members=Count('created')
        ).order_by('month')
    return queryset
```

This is my group by function, how I can get zero if no value is present for a particular month

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "total_members": 9,
            "month": "2021-02-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "total_members": 3,
            "month": "2021-03-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the output I am getting now, As there is no value for January, there is no output, what I wanted is zero for the month of January

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use [`Coalesce`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) for this, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Value as V
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce


def get_queryset(self):
    date = datetime.date.today()
    current_year = date.today().year
    queryset = Subscription.objects.filter(created__year=current_year)\
        .exclude(user__is_staff=True).values(
            month=TruncMonth('created')
        ).annotate(
            total_members=Coalesec(Count('created'), V(0))
        ).order_by('month')
    return queryset
```